# should std::copy() or std::move() of empty range require valid destination?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

The `std::move()` in the code below issues a runtime warning when compiled in Visual Studio 2013 (with Debug configuration) because it detects that `dest` is a `nullptr`.  However, the source range is empty, so `dest` should never be accessed.
The C++ standard may be unclear as to whether this should be allowed?
It states:  *Requires: result shall not be in the range [first,last).*
A `nullptr` would seem to satisfy that requirement.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    int* dest = nullptr;
    // The range [begin(vec),end(vec)) is empty, so dest should never be accessed.
    // However, it results in an assertion warning in VS2013.
    std::move(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), dest);
}
```

Comment: @KerrekSB: There's nothing magical about `begin` though. I could make my own `begin` and `end` methods that both returned null. How would that violate anything?

Comment: @Mehrdad: It wouldn't, it would just be totally pointless -- you could only ever have empty containers. That's why it's a sensible *warning*. It's like a dead code or unused warning, I guess.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It's not a warning, it's an assertion *error* here. But in any case, I don't see why it's pointless -- consider `std::array<int, 0>`. I don't know if the standard implements zero-sized `array`s, but if it did, I would think it is **completely reasonable** for `std::array::begin` and `std::array::end` to return null, no? (The zero-sized array itself would be reasonable too -- it might be used for a small-string optimization, and the user would specify `0` if he didn't want the optimization.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'm not sure now: it says that `begin() == end()` must be a "unique value" -- is that "unique per object", or "unique per array type"? In the latter case a null pointer would be fine, and indeed an assertion is too much.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't know, but I suspect the wording was exactly specified to allow the usage of a null pointer.

Comment: @Mehrdad: For what it's worth, GCC 4.8.1 does it exactly like that.

Comment: @KerrekSB: There we go :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not only does the *Requires:* clause need to be satisfied, but everything in the *Effects:* and *Returns:* clause needs to be satisfied as well.  Let's go through them:

> *Effects:* Copies elements in the range `[first,last)` into the range `[result,result + (last - first))` starting from `first` and
>   proceeding to `last`.

As `first == last`, then the range `[result, result + 0)` must be a valid range.

[iterator.requirements.general]/p7 states:

> A range `[i,i)` is an empty range;  ... `Range [i,j)` is valid if and only if `j` is reachable from `i`.

And p6 of the same section states:

> An iterator `j` is called reachable from an iterator `i` if and only
>   if there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression `++i`
>   that makes `i == j`.

From these paragraphs I conclude that given:

```
int* dest = nullptr;
```

Then `[dest, dest)` forms a valid empty range.  So the first sentence in the *Effects:* paragraph looks ok to me:

> For each non-negative integer `n < (last - first)`, performs `*(result + n) = *(first + n)`.

There are no non-negative integers `n < 0`, and so no assignments can be performed.  So the second sentence does not prohibit `dest == nullptr`.

> *Returns:* `result + (last - first)`.

[expr.add]/p8 specifically allows one to add 0 to any pointer value and the result compares equal to the original pointer value.  Therefore `dest + 0` is a valid expression equal to `nullptr`.  No problems with the *Returns:* clause.

> *Requires:* `result` shall not be in the range `[first,last)`.

I see no reasonable way to interpret that `dest` would be "in" an empty range.

> *Complexity:* Exactly `last - first` assignments.

This confirms that no assignments can be done.

I can find no statement in the standard that makes this example anything but well-formed.

Comment: I was hoping you'd come by. It seemed there weren't too many other people who could give an authoritative response. :)

Comment: The standard is written in a way that imposes no requirements on a call that does nothing (std::move() no container element); checking the destination, even if not accessed, would be clumsy and inefficient. 
I wonder, however, how bad a compiler bug it is, both formally and considering the difficulty of proving that no elements are being copied.

Comment: How about singular value iterators ([iterator.requirements.general]/p5)? Singular value iterator cannot be compared with anything. If `nullptr` would be considered a singular value iterator then `[nullptr, nullptr)` technically is not an empty range since technically we cannot do `==` to see that it is empty. (I do realize it would work on any sane compilator since C pointers allow here more than the abstract idea of an iterator.) So the question is: is `nullptr` a singular value iterator? And why?

Comment: @AdamBadura: Both [conv.ptr]/p1 and  [expr.eq]/p1 mention that `nullptr` can be equality compared.

Comment: @HowardHinnant It doesn't seem to matter here. For example `std::copy` will consider end iterator as past-the-end iterator and will not dereference it. Even if the actual value is not a past-the-end iterator. Similarly only because `nullptr` is comparable _as a pointer_ it doesn't necessarily mean that it is comparable _as an iterator_. Since as an iterator it _might_ be considered a singular value iterator. _If_ it would be so then `std::copy` would rightly consider `[nullptr, nullptr)` as an invalid range as it would do with any range build from singular value iterators.

Comment: @AdamBadura:  This was adopted for C++14: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3644.pdf

Comment: @HowardHinnant Does it mean, that pre-C++14 my concerns were indeed true? But with C++14 the are no longer true? Sadly I mostly function in pre-C++14 world. In fact quite often even pre-C++11. Which is terrible!

Comment: @AdamBadura:  It depends on your context.  If you want to talk language-lawyer, maybe, I don't know.  If you want to talk practical real-world code and compilers, there is no problem pre-C++14 that I have experienced in the last two decades.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Fully agree. I'm on the language-lawyer position here. I have even stated that no sane compiler should have problems with such use of `nullptr`.

Answer (score -1):

The debug build of STL in Visual Studio does additional parameter validation.  In this case, it is validating that dest is not null since it shouldn't be, which is failing.  The release build may very well act as you expect, never using dest but that doesn't make the input data valid.

The debug build of STL is trying to help you by saying, "your input is bad".  While the bad input might not be a problem in some circumstances, the validator can't know under what conditions you are passing it bad data.  Personally, I would much rather have VS tell me about bad input in debug builds than have a runtime exception thrown in production.

Sure, you might do something like this:

```
int* dest = nullptr;
if (vec.size() > 0) dest = realDest;
std::move(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), dest);
```

But the validator doesn't know that so it assumes the worst, especially since fixing it is very easy for you (just always pass in a valid output iterator) and not warning you about it could have terrible consequences on your application at runtime in production.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. I seems that the OP is more concerned with the standard and its particular wording. In this case, it looks like the standard is somewhat under specified.

Comment: Yeah you totally missed the point of the question... I don't think the OP needs an explanation of why debug builds are more useful for debugging than release builds. -1

Answer (score -1):

This answer is derived from the comment by @Philipp Lenk.  If he supplies an answer and you find it acceptable, choose his over mine and please up-vote his original comment.

> §25.1.5: Throughout this Clause, the names of template parameters are
>   used to express type requirement [...] if an algorithm’s template
>   parameter is OutputIterator, OutputIterator1, or OutputIterator2, the
>   actual template argument shall satisfy the requirements of an output
>   iterator.
>
> §24.2.4: A class or pointer type X satisfies the requirements of an
>   output iterator if X satisfies the Iterator requirements and the
>   expressions in Table 108 are valid and have the indicated semantics.
>   First line of the table: `*r = o` with the remark that `post: r is
>   incrementable.`

```
int* dest = nullptr;
*dest = 5;
++dest;
```

The above code is not valid.  You cannot assign to `*dest` in this case, therefore per the standard you cannot pass a nullptr in for the dest.

Comment: §24.2.4 is talking about the requirements on **types**, not *arguments*.

Comment: Thank you for giving me credit and formulating this answer, but i am afraid Mehrdad is right, it is talking about types and my original thought that it would be applicable in this case is wrong. As far as I understand it now, it would only be applicable if the nullptr constant had been passed to std::move directly, for in this case, the type would be nullptr_t

Comment: In that case, the example program is still invalid since `dest` is used as an output iterator.  As soon as you assign `nullptr` to `dest` in the example, `dest` is no longer a valid output iterator.  In order for something to be a valid iterator you must be able to perform the operation `*r = o` on it, which you can't do to `nullptr`.  The compiler lets you get away with assigning `nullptr` to `dest`, but as soon as you do, `dest` is no longer a valid output iterator and therefore you cannot pass it into something that takes an output iterator and expect valid results.

Comment: By this logic, `std::end(vec)` is not a valid input iterator either, right? So I don't think this logic is right.

Comment: The requirements of input iterators and output iterators are not the same.  `dest` is an output iterator which means you must be able to dereference and assign to it.  std::end(vec) in the example is used as an input iterator, assignability is not a requirement of an input iterator.

Comment: As mentioned before, I used to think the same way, but it is wrong. Dereferencability is merely the requirement for the iterator **type**, which in this case is int*, not nullptr_t, due to the line "int *dest=nullptr". And the int* type does satisfy all the requirements, the specific value is of no concern for those. Howard Hinnants answer explains it quite thoroughly.