# Calling std::string::assign(const CharT* s, size_type count) with count 0 safe?

Tags: c++, string, assign

Is the following code safe?

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    std::string s = "ABC";

    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign
    s.assign(nullptr, 0);
    
    assert(s.empty());
}
```

Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/SYTJlzc4DkzaUekv

---

Added this part in order to clarify my question point.

I expect that passing not only nullptr but also uninitialized pointer is safe as follows if size (length) parameter `n` is 0.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    std::string s = "ABC";

    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign
    char* uninitialized;
    s.assign(uninitialized, 0);
    
    assert(s.empty());
}
```

Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/UeSX0NWRPaS6OvqT

---

The actual code is a part of generic function.

I don't want to check the second argument size is 0 or not. But I'm not sure it is safe.

---

Added to describe why I don't want to check the second argument.

Here is a PoC code. I want to write the function as `func2()`. If the `std::string::assign()` call is safe, `func1()` is redundant for me.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

void func1(std::string& target, char* s, std::size_t n) {
    if (n == 0) target.clear();
    else target.assign(s, n);
}

void func2(std::string& target, char* s, std::size_t n) {
    target.assign(s, n);
}

int main() {
    char* uninitialized;
    std::size_t n = 0;
    {
        std::string s = "ABC";
        func1(s, uninitialized, n);
        assert(s.empty());
    }
    {
        std::string s = "ABC";
        func2(s, uninitialized, n);
        assert(s.empty());
    }
}
```

Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/PK8vIvw4XKrICsqe

---

According to https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/string.assign

> basic_string& assign(const charT* s, size_type n);
>
> Requires: s points to an array of at least n elements of charT.
>
> Throws: length_­error if n > max_­size().
>
> Effects: Replaces the string controlled by *this with a string of length n whose elements are a copy of those pointed to by s.

If n is 0 then s must contains at least 0 elements. So requirements are satisfied.
Replaces the string controlled by *this with a string of length 0. So the string controlled by *this is replaced with the empty string.

Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: *"I don't want to check the second argument size is 0 or not."* -- you are more concerned about this than checking for `nullptr`?

Comment: I guess that if the size `n` is 0, then the assign implementation doesn't access (dereference) the parameter `s`. But I'm not sure about that too.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo [Is assigning a nullptr to std::string safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771864/assign-a-nullptr-to-a-stdstring-is-safe).  The behavior is undefined -- a debug version of a compiler's runtime may even `assert` on that line, and that would be perfectly valid behavior.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo You may want to eliminate uncertainties from your question so that answers stay focused on what you meant to ask about. Case in point: I know `0` is a valid size if the pointer is a valid, non-null pointer-to-char. I'd have to look up (or wait for PaulMcKenzie to look  up) whether or not the `(nullptr, 0)` combination  is valid.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It is different from your linked question. The linked question's constructor expect null terminated string. But in my case, size parameter is given.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo So let's take this to the logical conclusion -- if what you are doing is ok, then why stop at `nullptr`?  Why can't any uninitialized, junk pointer be used if the number of elements is 0?

Comment: @JaMiT I could say I pass uninitialized char* instead of nullptr. Is this make  a difference for you?

Comment: Hmm... It seems that the nullptr makes a confusion. I should update my question. I will do it soo.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo An uninitialized pointer is not valid.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo -- That would be one bit of a surprise if the standard guarantees that bad pointers will be ignored if the argument is 0.  First time I've heard of anything like that, as it would go against anything I would expect from the standard.  Basically my argument is that a compiler **debug** runtime can legally halt your program on an assert if the pointer is null (or invalid).  A release version would probably not do anything.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Regarding the question you linked to: It deals with construction. `basic_string& assign( const CharT* s, size_type count );` when `count` is `0` is not described as well in the answer

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo [See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901903/is-it-valid-to-pass-nullptr-to-stdstringassign).  It basically seems to outline what I suspected.  A debug version can do the check, regardless if the size is 0.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  "Implementations are allowed to check validity of pointer. "  I think that it shouldn't be allowed if `n` is 0. Where is the standard description about that is allowed ?

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo -- If it's not in the standard, then it is more than likely implementation-defined.  No different than an implementation testing if the `std::sort` user-defined predicate is valid -- nowhere in the standard does it state that an implementation can do this, but you have implementations doing just that.  The onus is on you proving that implementations *must* adhere to your notion of not checking validity of pointers, and right now it seems you would be very hard-pressed in finding this ruling.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I think that assertion failed if the `s` is nullptr even if `n` is 0, the library doing too much (invalid check). For example libc++ (llvm) checks as follows https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/string#L1909-L1919

I think that  if the combination of nullptr and 0 is assertion failed in debug mode, the library should be fixed.

Comment: libstdc++ also allow 0 with nullptr combination. See the following three links:


https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L1440-L1445



https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/debug/debug.h#L122-L123



https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/debug/macros.h#L462-L463

Comment: Debug mode is allowed to do these checks -- that's why it's called "debug" mode.   It is up to the implementer on what they will check for -- if you have an issue, talk to the implementers.  Again and as an example, buggy predicates that do not adhere to a strict-weak-order *may* be able to work for certain algorithm functions, but that doesn't mean the implementation can't check for the buggy implementation in a debug runtime.   Debug mode is also able to check boundaries of arrays.  Where in the standard does it state that bounds checking shouldn't be done on regular arrays?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie bounds checking should be done only if the actual access is happened. My example never access nullptr or uninitialized pointer. I couldn't find any implementation that access nullptr in my case but if I found it, I will contant to implementer and send a pull request to fix the buggy implementation.

Comment: Well @eerorika is active here from what I remember, and he supplied the answer to the link I posted.  I am about to be inclined to close this as a duplicate, since what is at that link answers your question.  Any dispute, you can simply add to the comments there.

Comment: I'm not convinced about "Debug mode is allowed to do these checks". Because two major implementation g++ (libstdc++) and clang++(libc++) don't do that. The pointer is checked **only if n is NOT 0** in the debug mode. At least the standard is not said about how much debug checking is allowed. So the checking is decided by implementer and community discussion (in open source case). Checking the pointer only if n is NOT 0 is very reasonable decision. So the two major library do that.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo You _can_ however impose stronger checking when testing by linking with the sanitizer libraries (`asan` and `ubsan`) using these compiler options for `g++`/`clang++`: `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` - Those combined are capable of pinpointing a lot of problems.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo You observed that something has not been done, then concluded that the something is not allowed. This is an invalid deduction. You could conclude that the something is not *required*, but there are many allowed things that people simply choose not to do.

Comment: I referred to C++17 spec but in the C++20 spec defines it clearer.
https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/string.assign
At the paragraph 8 "Preconditions: [s, s + n) is a valid range."
And https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/iterator.requirements paragraph 11 "A counted range i+[0, n) is valid if and only if n == 0;or n is positive, i is dereferenceable, and 
++i + [0, -{-}n) is valid.
In my case, n == 0 so the range is valid. It perfectly satisfies the spec (C++20) even if i is nullptr or uninitialized pointer.